# Unstable answers from HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, networking, mvvm-light

I'm using a simple wrapper around HttpWebRequest, which returns a string in all cases: if answer is okay, it returns answer string, if something went wrong, it returns String.Empty.

```
    public async Task<string> FireAsync(string method, string postData, string url)
    {
        httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.Method = method; // HttpMethod
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json"; // ;odata=verbose

        try
        {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return String.Empty;
            }

            var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            var postStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            string data = await postStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

            return data ?? String.Empty; // if null, return empty
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that sometimes, it returns empty string. And sometimes, it returns answer after a really long period of time. I didn't recall similar problems while using WebClient.

Is anybody else having same experience?

Comment: are you closing your response or response stream?

Comment: Don't shallow exceptions,it contains the answer to your question

Comment: @adaam hm... not sure, that it will help, but i'll add closing to both

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx have a look at that - it may help you.

Comment: @ArsenMkrt the problem is that i cant reproduce the error... But you're right, i'll see what's inside of the exception

Comment: put a logging inside the catch block, and you will get the message next time the issue repeat.